# OMNET++: How to create a timer event that fires on each second?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using `OMNET++` with `INET` Framework 4.0. How can I create a Timer in my custom Mobility Module to fire at each second so that I can move my `AdhocHost` every time my timer event fires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `OMNeT++` [self-messages](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:self-messages) are timers.
To achieve your goal you should create a `cMessage` object, schedule it using [`scheduleAt()`](https://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cSimpleModule.html#a97c57271ca2fc95225ed8514750cac27), then in `handleMessage()` reschedule it every time when it expires.
For example:

```
// somewhere in simple module class declaration (*.h)
simtime_t timerInterval;
cMessage * timer;

// in initialize()
timerInterval = 1.0; // one second
timer = new cMessage("one second timer");
scheduleAt(simTime() + timerInterval, timer);

// in handleMessage()
if (msg == timer) {
   // do something

   scheduleAt(simTime() + timerInterval, timer);  // rescheduling
}

// in finish()
cancelAndDelete(timer);
```

---

By the way: there are a lot of examples of using self-messages in `OMNeT++` samples, especially in Tictoc.